# Исходный поворот элемента при загрузке страницы

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте уважаемые форумчани.
Есть скрипт, который поворачивает картинку на -6 градусов и обратно на -2 градуса.

Но при старте страницы картинки стоят на 0 градусов.
Что нужно дописать в этом скрипте(Jquery), чтобы при загрузке страницы картинки стояли не на 0 градусов а на -2 градуса.

Пробовал через СSS задать исходное положение картинки на -2 градуса но результат мне не понравился.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


$.fn.rotate = function(value, duration) {
  this.stop().animate({
    rotate: value
  }, {
    step: function(now, fx) {
      $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
    },
    duration: duration
  });
}
 
 
$('.image-1, .image-2').hover(
   
   function() {
    $(this).rotate(-6, 300);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).rotate(-2, 300);
  }
);


});
```

```css
.image-1{
width: 300px; 
height: 300px;
margin: 4%; 
}

.image-2{
width: 300px;  
height: 300px;
margin: 4%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   </head>

  
  <body>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/m6P51Qx/1.jpg" alt>

<img class="image-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/5kHjDCD/2.jpg" alt>

  </body>
 

</html>
```

Comment: Не забывайте отмечать "галочкой" слева от ответа ответы, которые ответили на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.rotate = function(value, duration) {
    this.stop().animate({
      rotate: value
    }, {
      step: function(now, fx) {
        $(this).css('transform', 'rotate(' + now + 'deg)');
      },
      duration: duration
    });
  }

  $('.image-1, .image-2').hover(
    function() {
      $(this).rotate(-6, 300);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).rotate(-2, 300);
    }
  );

  $('.image-1, .image-2').rotate(-2, 300);
});
```

```css
.image-1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 4%;
}

.image-2 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 4%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<img class="image-1" src="https://i.ibb.co/m6P51Qx/1.jpg" alt>
<img class="image-2" src="https://i.ibb.co/5kHjDCD/2.jpg" alt>
```

Comment: Ё маё))) Такую мелочь упустил)) Спасибо вам большое)))

Comment: На здоровье. Успехов!